# Moving my existing email-password based accounts over to Firebase Auth

Tags: email, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

My existing auth system is email-and-password. Going to be using Firebase Auth in the near future for handling social logins. How do I deal with my current accounts?

One option is to treat email/password as a "custom" auth scheme with Firebase Auth.

Other option is to add (actually move) my current accounts to Firebase Auth under **their** email/password auth scheme.  This obviously offers long-term convenience as I wouldn't have to maintain a hybrid auth system for ever.

This would mean creating my existing users as new email/password users under Firebase Auth, then simply stop using my existing system and move over completely to Firebase Auth.

Here's the problem with doing this: being a good little boy, I used nonces and Bcrypt to encrypt each password, so I now have no way of recovering the original passwords (which would be required to seamlessly create email/password accounts in Firebase)... asking users to set their passwords again for (seemingly) no reason is bad UX.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has a tool that allows you to import users and their encrypted passwords. Bcrypt is one of the supported encryption formats. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth.

Comment: Getting an "unexpected error" when I try the import. Is there any place where I can check for error/log messages?

Comment: The import worked when I switched to using CSV instead of JSON (must have been making a mistake with my JSON).